# WYSIWYG editor choices

Tags: php, javascript

CKEditor is a very good HTML editor. However, when I paste some html structure and shift to the WYSIWYG mode, the editor automatically reform the html structure which I do not expect, and therefore the original html layout is changed.

I would like to explore if there would be other alternative editors that can preserve the entire codes with the these characteristics:

1. capture external css file to become inner editor css
2. capture external template for inner editor usage
3. be able to integrate with elfinder 2.0
4. function similar to ckeditor, when applying `contenteditable="false"`, that particular div will be frozen and cannot be edited.

Comment: your code is not code, and you need to expand on what you have tried and what you want to do, tinymce is my choice but it is what it is

Comment: I use Ctrl+K to surround the points so that they will be more easily to read, rather than merge into single line. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have always used TinyMCE: http://www.tinymce.com/

It is highly customizable, and compatible in most browsers including mobile.

Comment: which configuration shall I use to totally disable auto formatting? Thanks.